# is it possible to remove unrelated commits after merging master

Tags: git, github

I have a feature branch, after I did a git pull origin master it was full of conflicts, so I fixed it and did a commit then continued working on my feature branch.

But when I pushed and made a PR, it also included other unrelated commits from other branches. So now it's hard to review because on github is showing unrelated files that have been changed.

I only merged the default branch to my current branch, this has never happened to me before.

Comment: Typically you shouldn't be seeing the other work, assuming it already exists in the `master` target branch.  Did you possibly alter the lines which are showing up with changes?

Comment: I made the PR then after a few days it had a bunch of conflicts, so I merged all of the upcoming changes, then commit and made the changes again on my branch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you would rebase your feature branch on top of `origin/master`, and resolve the conflicts then.

```
git switch my_feature_branch
git rebase origin/master
```

Then your PR would only include your work, since said work was replayed on top of the updated `origin/master` branch, target of your PR.

Comment: at this point rebasing is very difficult, as I don't remember everything the changes I made on my feature branch. Is there an easier approach?

Comment: @KevinBryan I understand. I will leave this answer as a best practice to use in your future PR

Comment: I just did a rebase and seems clean now. However when I try to push, it says "Your branch and orgin/featurebranch have diverged". Should I pull or force push?

Comment: @KevinBryan Yes, that is the idea behind rebase: you are replaying your history, making a new one: you must force push it.

Comment: @KevinBryan Strange. It depends on what was rebase on top of the target branch. I wonder if a new PR would only list the right commits.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231601/discussion-between-vonc-and-kevin-bryan).